# mysql select row and count each connected distinct row

Tags: mysql, select, count

table one

```
product  c  
==========================================
sample_1    Line
sample_1    LLk
sample_1    LLk
sample_1    LLk
sample_1    LLk
sample_2    LLk
sample_3    LLk
sample_2    LLk
sample_3    LLk
sample_2    Line
```

Plus this table two

```
a    h        r 
==========================================
LLk  sample_1  gw
LLk  sample_2  okp
LLk  sample_3  ijof
Line xe     rr3
LLk  sample_4  gr2
Line xx2       o3
```

Finally will be like this..

based on searching from table 2 where a=LLk

this is the table 3 which generated from table 1 and table 2

```
product  counts
============================
sample_1    4
sample_2    1
sample_3    2
sample_4    0
```

the detail link for this question
http://pastebin.com/ds0iS4GU

Comment: how `sample_2`  counts is 1?? i think count should b 2.. will u plz write the exact condition

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the answer you are looking for

`select h, count(t1.product) from t2 LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.c=t2.a and t1.product=t2.h where t2.a='LLk' group by t2.h`

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this?

```
select product, count(a) 
from table_two 
inner join table_one on product=h and c=a
where a = 'LLk'
group by product
```

Comment: Your solution will not return `sample_4`.

Comment: whoops didn't see sample_4, it should just need a left join then, looks as though praveen already answered it